# If cell contains value n, how can I create a column of n cells, each containing value n (and then repeat with another cell)?

Tags: excel, formula, vba

For the sake of simplicity, let's say I have a column of 5 numbers as follows:-

```
8
15
8
3
26
```

What I want to do is create a column composed firstly of 8 cells containing the value '8', then 15 cells containing the value '15', then 8 cells containing the value '8', and so on. This example would therefore result in a column length of 60 cells (however, my real-life column has over 200 numbers and would result in a column of about 2500 numbers!).

Is this possible? Would it need a formula or a macro? (I'm not very adept with either, I'm afraid, so apologies if this is a no-brainer.) Any suggestions very welcome.

Comment: which software do you use? excel? which version? if so you need to create simple VBA code- 2 loops one within the other...

Comment: Oops - sorry; using Excel 2000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Public Sub Test()

    PopulateColumn Range("A1"), Range("B1")

End Sub


Public Sub PopulateColumn(ByVal rngSourceStart As Range, ByVal rngTargetStart As Range)

    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngTarget As Range

    Set rngSource = rngSourceStart
    Set rngTarget = rngTargetStart

    Dim iValue As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    While rngSource.Value <> ""
        iValue = rngSource.Value
        For i = 1 To rngSource.Value
            rngTarget.Value = iValue
            Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(1, 0)
        Next
        Set rngSource = rngSource.Offset(1, 0)
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: WOW! The _only_ part of that macro I thought I _might_ understand was Range("A1"), Range("B1") (nothing after it makes any sense to me at all); but I just replaced A1 with the column reference that contained the data, B1 with the column I wanted the result in, ran the macro and - it. Just. Worked. Awesome! Many thanks raybiss.

Comment: Could you accept the answer please? I need the points to help another forum in Area 51 (beta). Thanks!