# Excel macro to incrementally number identical cells in a sorted column, resetting count to 1 when cell content changes

Tags: excel, numbers, vba

This is a follow-on from a previous question ([If cell contains value n, how can I create a column of n cells, each containing value n (and then repeat with another cell)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221446/if-cell-contains-value-n-how-can-i-create-a-column-of-n-cells-each-containing)). 
I have a column of numbers composed of x rows of value x, then y rows of value y, and so on; to give a simple example:

2
2
5
5
5
5
5
2
2
3
3
3
(etc - the actual list is over 2500 rows long and contains values between 2 and 200.)

What I need is a macro that would incrementally number each occurrence of the number, resetting the count to 1 whenever the value changes. So the above list would generate a column as follows: -

2 - 1
2 - 2
5 - 1
5 - 2
5 - 3
5 - 4
5 - 5
2 - 1
2 - 2
3 - 1
3 - 2
3 - 3
..etc.

I'm guessing the fact that the column is x rows of value x, y rows of value y (etc) isn't that important but I mention it in case it's useful. I'm using Excel 2000 (and am almost totally clueless about VBA). Any help very welcome.

Comment: Would a simple formula do, or do you absolutely need a macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you need the earlier macro to encompass this requirement, you can use this version, which includes occurrence ID beside each of the repetitions.

```
Public Sub Test()

    PopulateColumn Range("A1"), Range("B1")

End Sub


Public Sub PopulateColumn(ByVal rngSourceStart As Range, ByVal rngTargetStart As Range)

    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngTarget As Range

    Set rngSource = rngSourceStart
    Set rngTarget = rngTargetStart

    Dim iValue As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    While rngSource.Value <> ""
        iValue = rngSource.Value
        For i = 1 To rngSource.Value
            rngTarget.Value = iValue
            rngTarget.Offset(0, 1).Value = i
            Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(1, 0)
        Next
        Set rngSource = rngSource.Offset(1, 0)
    Wend

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a formula, you could use this:

`=if(A2=A1,B1+1,1)`

Put this in cell B2, assuming that the first number (2) is in cell A1. You only need to put `1` in cell B1 and after that fill in the formula to the bottom.

Comment: Brilliant! That works fine - many thanks. (I just assumed I'd need a macro as that's what my previous question required. Like I said, I'm pretty clueless about this.) Thanks again.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I learned my lesson and made sure that the OP's data required it not to be sorted this time ;). Otherwise, I'd use `COUNTIF`.